# Magento upgrade from 2.4.2-p1 to 2.4.3 problems

Tags: magento-upgrade, magento2.4.3

When I try to upgrade from 2.4.2-p1 to 2.4.3 I get:

Root `composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.3]`

Steps:
php7.4

```
bin/magento maintenance:enable

/usr/bin/php7.4 /usr/local/bin/composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3 --no-update

/usr/bin/php7.4 /usr/local/bin/composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

Check composer version if its not 2 then update it.
Magento 2.4.3 requires 2.x composer version.

```
sudo composer self-update --2

composer install
```

Comment: Hi 
I already run composer 2

Comment: Any other idear?

Answer (score 0):

You can go through [Magento Official Doc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html) for the same.
it will help you.

Thanks

Comment: Dosent work-....